# "Fre3of9x" Barcode font, won't load

Tags: css, fonts

So, I'm trying to load a "Barcode" font that will replace normal text to barcode on my webpage.

Now I'm  new of using fonts. The font I'm trying to use is this:

http://www.fontsupply.com/fonts/F/Fre3of9x.html `FRE3OF9X.TTF`

The error message is this: `Failed to decode downloaded font:`

I can see, the font is loading `304` in network console. So what is causing this problem?

**HTML**

```
<div class="barcode"><span class="barcodeText">*11111*</span></div>
```

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FRE3OF9X';
  src: url('/fonts/FRE3OF9X.TTF');
}
.barcodeText{
  font-family: 'FRE3OF9X', 'Georgia', serif;; 
}
```

**Result**

```
*11111*
```

I also got this message `OTS parsing error: maxp: failed to parse table`. But I do not really know what it is for.

**FIDDLE**

https://jsfiddle.net/f2a6gcvu/

**EDIT**
I did not solve this, but changed font. 3 of 9 works just fine.

https://www.searchfreefonts.com/free/3-of-9-barcode.htm

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Or something else where we can look through your problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the .TTF file through a webfont generator such as https://www.web-font-generator.com or http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator ?

Comment: @tR4xX Updated with fiddle!

Comment: @GerritBertier I tried your first link and got this: https://wfg-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/0acdf652654d608ab519587f40b24a3e/preview.html if i understand correct the font wont create barcode? But when i open the font on computer i see barcodes... fontsqurriel: says file is corrupted.. But in the fiddle i load it direct from the web...

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the generator it seems, but the generated .TTF works fine in Photoshop. I haven't tested it as a webfont though.
The Font Squirrel generator however, tells me the font I'm uploading is corrupt. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about fonts to be able to help you debug the font...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're getting the decode error is because the font actually *is* corrupt. Running it through [TTX](https://github.com/behdad/fonttools) (a utility for switching font representations between binary and XML form) gives us this:

```
> ttx FRE3OF9X.TTF
Dumping "FRE3OF9X.TTF" to "FRE3OF9X.ttx"...
Dumping 'GlyphOrder' table...
Error: cmap subtable is reported as having zero length:
    platformID 1, platEncID 0,  format 0 offset 20. Skipping table.
Dumping 'head' table...
Dumping 'hhea' table...
Dumping 'maxp' table...
Dumping 'OS/2' table...
Dumping 'hmtx' table...
Error: cmap subtable is reported as having zero length:
    platformID 1, platEncID 0,  format 0 offset 20. Skipping table.
Dumping 'cmap' table...
Dumping 'loca' table...
Dumping 'glyf' table...
Dumping 'name' table...
Dumping 'post' table...
```

As the `cmap` structure contains the information about which character a font supports, a broken cmap subtable is a terminal error. You can try to  derive the broken data from other cmap subtables (which is what Photoshop is probably doing) but that's not guaranteed to do the right thing. Browsers err on the side of caution, so this font is simply going to get rejected.

What to do: 1. report this font as broken to the website so they can either have it fixed or removed, 2. pick a new font (I see you already did that), and 3. probably grab yourself a copy of TTX for checking bad fonts in the future.

Comment: Thank for you. I will check TTX for sure!